# Как получить ссылку href из a-тега с Xpath

Tags: c#, html, парсер, xpath

Имеется вот такой кусок html кода :

```
<a href="/linc...." style="width:140px;" title="First linc">
First Link
</a>
```

Вот так я могу вытянуть `First linc` :

> //*[@class='cell-first name']/a

А как получить значение `href` ?

Comment: `//*[@class='cell-first name']/a/@href`

Comment: @tym32167 возвращает `First linc`

Comment: А чем парсите? Как ищете ноды?

Comment: Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/752573/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/752593#752593) я писал парсер и вытаскивал ссылку так `x.Attributes["href"].Value`

Comment: @tym32167 Воспользовался вашим примеров из ссылки => `Attributes["href"].Value`

Comment: @tym32167 помогло. спасибо. можете дать ответ, что бы я его принял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании библиотеки [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) при наличии элемента его атрибут можно получить следующим образом:

```
var href = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
```