# Как получить адрес из ссылки

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Имеется кусок html

```
<a href="?downloadletter=30985" target="_blank" class="articllink"><span class="nobr">№ 01И-3209/17 от 21.12.2017</span></a>        <font class="nobr file_format"><IMG height="16" alt="pdf-формат" hspace="5" src="/i/images/ico_pdf.gif" width="16" border="0" title="pdf-формат">66 Кб</font>
```

Вопрос: как из него получить адрес ссылки?

```
?downloadletter=30985
```

С помощью библиотеки HtmlAgilityPack [как здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/754717/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-href-%D0%B8%D0%B7-a-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D1%81-xpath) описано не выходит, т. к. `Attributes` возвращают `null`.

Делал так:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(str);
string cc = doc.DocumentNode.Attributes["href"].Value;
```

Comment: Значит элемент `a` не был получен. Покажите, как его получаете.

Comment: var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(str);
string cc = doc.DocumentNode.Attributes["href"].Value;

Answer (score 5):

Для того чтобы получить атрибут `href` необходимо сначала выбрать ноду в которой находиться этот артрибут. В вашем случае это нода `a`.

Пример получения ссылки:

```
    var str = @"<a href=""?downloadletter=30985"" target=""_blank"" class=""articllink""><span class=""nobr"">№ 01И-3209/17 от 21.12.2017</span></a>
                <font class=""nobr file_format""><IMG height=""16"" alt=""pdf-формат"" hspace=""5"" src=""/i/images/ico_pdf.gif"" width=""16"" border=""0"" title=""pdf-формат"">66 Кб</font>";
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(str);
    var linkNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
    var link = linkNodes.First().Attributes["href"].Value;
```

Comment: помогло, спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад был помочь.

Comment: @rawman Галочка слева - щелк.