# Параллельные GET запросы C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, xnet

Пытаюсь организовать запросы к сайту в несколько потоков, но ни чего адекватного не выходит.

```
    private Thread th;
    private List<Thread> threadList;
    private static uint counts = 3516949269;
    public static object lockers = new object();
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        threadList = new List<Thread>();

        int num = 0;
        while (num < 10)
        {
            th = new Thread(Count) { IsBackground = false };
            threadList.Add(th);
            th.Start();
            num++;
        }
    }

   public static void Count()
     {
         while (true)
         {
            lock (lockers)
             {
              Checker(counts);
              counts--;
             }
        }
     }

private static void Checker(uint countr)
{
    try
    {
           using (HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest())
           {
              string s = "https:/ccmp.fc/?id=" + countr

               string text2 = httpRequest.Get(s).ToString();

                   File.AppendAllText(countr + ".txt", text2);
               }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Использовал библиотеку xNet. Подскажите как более грамотно организовывать

Comment: Я как то [писал про асинхронный парсер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752593/179763), поглядите, может будет интересно

Comment: @tym32167 то что нужно