# Semaphore в TPL

Tags: c#, tpl

В моей программе доступ к функции должно иметь только определенное количество потоков. Есть следующий код:

```
int totalTasksExecute = 3, currentTasksExecute = 0;
Task[] tasks = new Task[totalTasksExecute];
foreach(ObjModel obj in Objs)
{
    if (currentTasksExecute == totalTasksExecute)
    {
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        currentTasksExecute = 0;
    }
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    tasks[currentTasksExecute++] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetWebInfo(obj));
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Так как он встречается несколько раз, то я решил оформить в виде отдельного класса. В классе для одновременного ограничения доступа к функции я использую Semaphore.

```
public class MultiTasks<T>
{
    private readonly Action<T> _callback;
    private readonly Semaphore semaphore;
    private readonly List<T> ts;
    private readonly AutoResetEvent[] waitHandles;

    private int Count;

    public MultiTasks(Action<T> callback, int maxRunTasks, List<T> objListForTask)
    {
        ts = objListForTask;
        _callback = callback;
        semaphore = new Semaphore(maxRunTasks, maxRunTasks);
        waitHandles = new AutoResetEvent[objListForTask.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < waitHandles.Length; i++)
            waitHandles[i] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    }
    public void Start(int waitMilliSeconds)
    {
        Count = 0;
        foreach(T obj in ts)
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                semaphore.WaitOne();
                _callback(obj);
                waitHandles[Count].Set();
                Interlocked.Increment(ref Count);
                Thread.Sleep(waitMilliSeconds);
                semaphore.Release();
            });
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles);
    }
}
```

Вызываю таким образом:

```
MultiTasks<ObjModel> multiTasks = 
   new MultiTasks<ObjModel>(GetWebInfo, 3, objs.ToList());
multiTasks.Start(500);
```

Вопрос в том, что в первом случае время обработки занимает около 30 сек, то во втором случае в 2 раза больше. Может быть класс не правильно реализовал? Или не правильно использую Semaphore?

Comment: просто интересуюсь - какую задачу вы решаете этим кодом?

Comment: @tym32167 сначала получаю количество объектов через web запрос, затем с помощью foreach для каждого объекта получаю информацию так же через web запрос. Чтобы ускорить данный процесс, применил параллельное программирование.

Comment: Если вы работаете с вебом, то есть с сетью, то есть с тем, что не ест процессор, то вероятно вам надо не параллельное программирование применять, а асинхронное.

Comment: поглядите вот [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/752573/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/752593#752593), я там делал что то подобное тому, что вы описали

Comment: @tym32167 я использую async/await операторы при запросе данных. В моем случаем объектов много, поэтому чтобы ускорить процесс, я распараллеливаю. Спасибо, попробую с вашим вариантом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы делаете что то, что должно работать параллельно, но не более N потоков одновременно, может, имеет смысл пользоваться готовыми конструкциями? 
Как пример:

```
int i = 0;
Enumerable.Range(1, 100).AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(3).ForAll(x =>
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref i);
    Console.WriteLine($"Processing {x} - threads there - {i}");
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref i);
});
```

Вывод будет что то типа

```
Processing 1 - threads there - 1
Processing 2 - threads there - 1
Processing 4 - threads there - 3
Processing 6 - threads there - 3
Processing 7 - threads there - 3
Processing 8 - threads there - 3
Processing 9 - threads there - 3
.........
Processing 93 - threads there - 3
Processing 94 - threads there - 3
Processing 95 - threads there - 3
Processing 96 - threads there - 3
Processing 97 - threads there - 3
Processing 98 - threads there - 3
Processing 99 - threads there - 3
Processing 100 - threads there - 3
Processing 19 - threads there - 3
Processing 20 - threads there - 2
Processing 5 - threads there - 3
```

То есть не более 3 одновременно запущенных потока.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось все просто и изящно!)