# C# Организовать многопоточный парсинг через прокси

Tags: c#, многопоточность, парсер, http, proxy

Ищу уже который день способ парсить страницы как можно быстрее и эффективней.

Парсинг происходит через прокси, так как если с одного ип делать слишком частые запросы на сайт(который парсим) возвращаются ошибки о временной блокировки (анти ddos).

Мне нужно просто загружать страницы, т.е. параметры передавать не нужно. Обычные Get запросы.

1. Какие классы лучше использовать? Я использовал `HttpWebResponse/Request` и `WebResponse/Request`.
   У этих классов у меня возникает иногда трабла с proxy, некоторые адреса очень долго не отвечают и потоки в которых делю запрос зависают. Возможно есть другие более эффективные способы сделать GET запрос через прокси? Мб стоит использовать другую библиотеку, например CURL?
2. Как эффективней организовать работу с потоками? Использовать просто массив потоков? Использовать трэдПул? Смотреть в сторону асинхронности?

Если есть возможность предоставьте наиболее эффективный и простой пример с многопоточным совершение GET запросов через прокси.

Comment: Я когда-то писал [пример парсера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/752573/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/752593#752593). Но как он будет работать с прокси я без понятия

Comment: В основе всего - всёравно сокет. Можно попробовать GET запросы делать через сокет. (если http) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862890, а по поводу http-прокcи нужно в HOST передавать сайт, а в адрес коннекта сокета писать параметры прокси. Вот пример сокета с прокси cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread708014.html

Comment: @nick_n_a в чем смысл использования сокетов для простого гет запроса?

Comment: @tym32167 много подводных камней. Например в вашем примере, нужно отключать заголовок 100-continue. Нужно ставить try-catch что б обработать ответ отличный от 200. На обработку стрима теряется быстродействие.

Comment: @nick_n_a тогда, для запросов надо асинхронные методы сокета использовать, чтобы поток не блочить. То есть сокеты взять от вас, асинхронщину от меня :)

Comment: 1. Не важно, что вы используете, если у вас прокси не стабильно работают. 2. Эффективно можно через асинхронность, tpl dataflow хорошо подойдёт.