# System.IndexOutOfRangeException. dotnet core. tasks

Tags: c#, .net, task

у меня есть следующий код:

```
var workers = new Task<string>[workersCount];
var urls = new string[workersCount];
while (Numbers.HasNext)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < workersCount; i++)
    {
        urls[i] = $"{URL}{id}_{Numbers.Get()}";

        workers[i] = new Task<string>(() =>
        {
            using (var wb = new WebClient())
            {
                wb.Encoding = encoding;
                return wb.DownloadString(urls[i]);
            }
        });

        workers[i].Start();
    }

    Task.WaitAll(workers);
}
```

workersCount = 5. На вызове Task.WaitAll(workers) я получаю:  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Index was outside the bounds of the array." При отладке видно, что в момент исключения переменная i = 5, хотя такого быть не должно. Где может происходить еще один инкремент и как это исправить?

Comment: Что у вас первый цикл while делает?

Comment: у меня есть класс Numbers, его метод Get отдает int. т.к чисел очень много и их хранить нигде нельзя, он генерирует их налету при вызове Get. HasNext - bool свойство. т.е цикл while выполняется пока у Numbers есть числа.

Comment: "При отладке видно, что в момент исключения переменная i = 5, хотя такого быть не должно." Почему такое быть не должно? Цикл for увеличил переменную i с 4 до 5, потом проверил условие- условие не выполнилось, произошел выход из цикла

Comment: Зачем сздавать таск для синхронной операции, если можно [сразу вызвать асинхронную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/752573/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/752593#752593)?

Comment: А что касается вашей проблемы - классичаская ошибка с замыканием переменной i. Перед созданием таска сохраните `var temp = i;`, и внутри таска пользуйтесь переменной temp

Comment: "Зачем сздавать таск для синхронной операции, если можно сразу вызвать асинхронную?" необходимо было дать пользователю изменять количество воркеров(тасков). страниц очень много, и создавать миллиарды тасков сразу, не хочется.

Comment: Так не создавайте миллиарды, создавайте сколько надо, это никак не противоречит ни моему коментарию, ни ответу по моей ссылке.