# C# HTTP синтаксис / парсер

Tags: c#, http

Где можно получить точный синтаксис HTTP запросов/ответов?

Например:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
```

Может ли быть без пробелов?

```
POST/HTTP/1.1
```

и т.д

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: `точный синтаксис HTTP запросов/ответов` вы о чем вообще? Опишите, какую задачу решаете?

Comment: пишу парсер) получаю string хочу сделать обьект

Comment: Парсер типа [такого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/752573/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/752593#752593)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не может быть без пробелов.

Точный синтаксис можно получить из документа, описывающего стандарт HTTP 1.1: [RFC 7230: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and Routing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230)

Вот как описана строка `Request line` в [секции 3.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1):

> A request-line begins with a method token, followed by a single space
> (SP), the request-target, another single space (SP), the protocol version, and ends with CRLF.
>
> ```
>  request-line   = method SP request-target SP HTTP-version CRLF
> ```

Comment: CRLF - 0x0D0x0A (\r\n)?

Comment: @MikeWaters верно

Comment: получается первая всегда request line а остальные в любом порядке?

Comment: @MikeWaters да, порядок заголовков не важен, но есть некоторые рекомендации относительно порядка, все в РФС написано