# C# много POST запросов в цикле

Tags: android, c#, http, post, xamarin

Необходимо выполнить очень много POST запросов на сайт, получить ответ (типо "1,2,3.." добавить в массив и отправить запросы на другой URL. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, как можно правильно это реализовать с помощью c# Xamarin Android. Вот пример как это делаю я (но много запросов пропускается, а потом вообще приложение вылетает):

```
public string[500] Products;
public string[] Numbers;

public void myStart()
 {
  for (int i = 0; Products.Length > i; i++)
   {
     POST(TokenKey, Products[i]);
   }
}

async void POST(string TokenKey, string product)
 {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
  request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://my.web.com/getProductList?product=" + product);
  request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
  request.Headers.Add("Authorization", TokenKey);
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
  var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

  DecodeResponse(result);
}

DecodeResponse(string line)
{
  Numbers = line.Split(',');
  if(Numbers.Length > 0){
    for (int i = 0; Numbers.Length > i; i++)
    {
      REMOVENUMBER(TokenKey, Numbers[i]);
    }
  }
}

async void REMOVENUMBER(string TokenKey, string number)
{
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
  request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://my.web.com/remove?number=" + number);
  request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
  request.Headers.Add("Authorization", TokenKey);
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
  var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: у вас метод `POST` асинхронный, но вы не ждете его окончания

Comment: то же самое и про метод `REMOVENUMBER`

Comment: так есть await? как можно его подождать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ожидаются таски (Task), а не Void.

Comment: То есть цикл приостановиться и будет ждать завершения Task?можно пример?

Comment: @PlagiAtKanal [Вполне хороший пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752593/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо сейчас буду смотреть

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня не получается, можете написать кратко решение по моему примеру?

Comment: @PlagiAtKanal Не, я вам тут не помощник, просто немного дополнил предыдущего оратора и указал ссылку на пример того, как работать с async.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вроде разобрался, все работает... спасибо!