# HttpClient Получить ответ ассинхронно

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Пытаюсь получить ответ от сайта без блокировки UI:

```
async Task<string> HttpGetOnlineAsync(string params)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
        Task<Stream> result = hc.GetStreamAsync(URL + params);
        Stream stream = await result;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        return await reader.ReadToEndAsync(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

И делее вызываю метод:

```
var o = JObject.Parse(await HttpGetOnlineAsync(params));
```

На строке:

```
Stream stream = await result;
```

Вылезает ошибка и перекидывает в дизассемблированный код.

---

Вот так все работает но фризит. Мне нужно сделать:

```
var resp = request.GetResponse();
```

async так как фризится UI:

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
    var resp = request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
     return null;
 }
```

---

Да хоть все в using оберни:

```
async Task<string> HttpGetOnlineAsync(string twitchname)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + twitchname + ClientID);
        {
            using (var resp = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                using (Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Все равно с ошибкой.

```
var resp = await request.GetResponseAsync()
```

Как будто код выполняется не дожидаясь await.

Comment: Ошибка то хоть какая?

Comment: ArgumentNullException: Значение не может быть неопределенным.

Comment: а почему не воспользоваться функцией [`GetStringAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync(v=vs.118).aspx)?

Comment: В таком виде даже не скомпилируется: `HttpGetOnlineAsync(string params)`

Comment: GetStringAsync Использовал. Task<Stream> result находится в Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Еще не вычислено})". Толи не успевает загрузится до обработки результата толи не запускается задача. HttpGetOnlineAsync(string params) - без async фризит UI

Comment: [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752593/179763)?

Comment: Я не загружаю страницу. Я получаю ответ от нее. В виде строки. Но отправка запроса (  Task<Stream> result = hc.GetStreamAsync(URL + params);) и чтение результата(reader.ReadToEndAsync(); ) фризит UI  если делать без async

Comment: `string params` действительно не компилируется. Покажите _компилирующйися_ код. В примере с `WebRequest` используется `URL`, в примере с `HttpClient` используется `URL + params`. Ну и так по мелочи: `HttpClient`, `Stream`, `StreamReader` - всё это нужно диспозить (используйте `using`).

Comment: Если из трех разных кусков кода работает только один - смотри чем конкретно они отличаются.