# Как правильно построить асинхронный/многопоточный клиент?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf

Есть WinForms клиент, функция которого обрабатывать файлы из определенной папки пользователя, шифровать, запаковывать их определенным образом и отправлять полученный пакет на wcf сервис.
Этот клиент уже был написан, у меня задача его ускорить.

---

Вот мои мысли и попытки:

1. **Пул Task-ов**. Его архитектура построена на пуле Task-ов. То есть документы на обработку складываются в очередь. Затем ранее запущенный Task, внутри которого цикл while(true), следит за этой очередью - берет первый документ, ищет или ждет для него свободный Task из массива пула тасков и дает таску задание:

   `TasksPool[index] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => document.Work(), _cancelWork);`

В методе происходил метод отправки документа на сервис:

```
wcfServiceClient.SendDocument(packet);
```

У меня возникли в голове такие мысли: когда Task доходит до отправки документа на сервис, и происходит отправка, он тормозит процесс(процесс с этим таском просто зависает и ждет завершения отправки) или как-то сам по умному уходит в ожидание, а его процесс подхватывает в это время работу другого таска? А также возникла мысль что зачем нужно использовать какой-то пул потоков, когда есть готовые средства распараллеливания типа Parallel?

2. **Попытка написать с Parallel.ForEach**.

   `Parallel.ForEach(files, file => new Document(wcfClient, file).Work())`

Просто скажу что лучше не стало, то есть например пул задач для 3-х тасков из 1-го пункта оказался быстрее, чему я очень удивлен. Есть предположение что затык в wcf клиенте...

3. **async await**

   `class Document
   {
     public async Task<bool> Work()
     {
       var sendDocumentResult = await    _photonServiceClient.SendDocumentAsync(edtPacket);
       return sendDocumentResult.Result;
     }
   }`

   `var tasks = files.Select(x => new Document(wcfClient, x).Work());`
   `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Думал что это решит проблему и процесс не будет простаивать при отправке документа - на деле также никаких преимуществ не дало, работает на уровне 2-го пункта.
И теперь я немного в смятении - получается простоев при отправке пакета на сервис не было, уже самый первый вариант работал как нужно? И если 1-й вариант работает быстрее остальных, то значит дело в wcf клиенте, в идеале нужно каждый instance на каждый поток? Но как это соорудить если мы работаем с тасками и не знаем в каком потоке мы фактически выполняемся и сколько потоков будет задействовано?

Comment: в третьем случае нужно избавится от `.Result;` - это превращает метод в синхронный. и второе: ты можешь создать столько тасков сколько захочешь. если задача ожидает пакетов от сети (i/o bound) - она ресурсов не ест. третье: не понял как ты `следил за тасками в цикле`? - это `buisy wait`?

Comment: @dgzargo он там ожидал завершения таска перед тем, как result вызвать

Comment: [вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752593/179763) асинхронного парсера. Но имейте ввиду, что если у вас большая часть времени тратится на вызов сервиса, то хоть как изголяйся, вызов сервиса с клиента не ускорить

Comment: @tym32167 именно! и метод стал синхронный!

Comment: @dgzargo не стал, если к моменту вызова result таска уже завершилась

Comment: @dgzargo погодите ка, я не понял код автора, он ждет таску, которая возвращает таск походу. Если так, то вы правы )))

Comment: @tym32167 судя по названию метода, он работает с сетью. а у нее пинг >10мс

Comment: не понимаю как он смог скомпилировать такой метод

Comment: @dgzargo не, я про то, что вот эта строчка `var sendDocumentResult = await    _photonServiceClient.SendDocumentAsync(edtPacket);` дожидается конца таска, то есть в `sendDocumentResult` после этого должен быть результат таска после выполнения асинхронной операции. Если жто так, то тогда тип этой переменной не таск, и вот это `sendDocumentResult.Result` к таскам не относится вообще

Comment: @tym32167 кажется я понял про что ты. он не должен был использовать `async/await` а вернуть сконфигуренный таск.

Comment: @tym32167 так пока тачка с await не завершилась и мы дошли до результата этой тачки я так понимаю что контекст синхронизации в это время перекидывает наш процесс на работу другой тачки, то есть процесс не простаивает. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, я приду домой и ещё раз проверю, попробую переписать с await-ами

Comment: Если вы ждете такск вот так `myTask.Result` - вы заблочили текущий тред, это плохо. Если вы ждете таск вот так `var something = await myTask;` - вы ждете асинхронно, то есть не блокируете эти ожиданием поток.