# Как сделать Get-запрос в многопотоке с пагинацией?

Tags: c#

Есть множество урл такого формат. `xxx.ru/печенье/page=1`,`xxx.ru/молоко/page=1`.
Как узнать последнюю страницу каждого урла? Если страница последняя, то там появляется текст "это последняя страница"

```
var html =="";
var index = 0; 
whilie (!html.Contains("это последняя страница"))
{
      index++;
      html = Get("xxx.ru/печенье/page="index);
}
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос практически копия [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752593/179763). Если вы не знаете последнюю страницу, то вам надо её узнать.

Comment: @tym32167 это не то. Допустим у меня сто урлов таких. И я хочу для каждого узнать последнюю страницу?

Comment: ну так вам парсить надо ответ и смотреть, универсального способа понять кол-во страниц для произвольного вебсайта нет в природе

Comment: @tym32167 неправильно расписал вопрос. Посмотрите в этот раз

Comment: Я просто не пойму как через Parallel.For сделать это @tym32167

Comment: `Как узнать последнюю страницу каждого урла?` - `Если страница последняя, то там появляется текст "это последняя страница"` вы задали вопрос и сами ответили на него, или я вас не понимаю

Comment: @tym32167 я хочу узнать последнюю страницу урла в каждом запросе. Через многопоток. я просто не пойму как через Parallel.For сделать это

Comment: через `parralel.for` никак. вам наверное надо что то типа producer-consumer

Comment: @tym32167 можно кусочек кода?

Comment: [Имплементация Producer/Consumer pattern](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/179763)